# I get this error when I install acpi-call-dkms

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, debian, linux-device-driver

```
$ sudo apt install acpi-call-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acpi-call-dkms
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/13.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 48.1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package acpi-call-dkms.
(Reading database ... 395855 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../acpi-call-dkms_1.1.0-5_all.deb ...
Unpacking acpi-call-dkms (1.1.0-5) ...
Setting up acpi-call-dkms (1.1.0-5) ...
Loading new acpi-call-1.1.0 DKMS files...
Building for 5.6.0-trunk-amd64
Building initial module for 5.6.0-trunk-amd64
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.6.0-trunk-amd64 (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package acpi-call-dkms (--configure):
 installed acpi-call-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 acpi-call-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**These are the contents of the the /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/make.log**

```
DKMS make.log for acpi-call-1.1.0 for kernel 5.6.0-trunk-amd64 (x86_64)
Thu 28 May 2020 06:26:56 PM IST
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-trunk-amd64'
  AR      /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/built-in.a
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.o
/var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.c: In function ‘init_acpi_call’:
/var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.c:356:53: error: passing argument 4 of ‘proc_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
                                                     &proc_acpi_operations);
                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.c:6:
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-trunk-common/include/linux/proc_fs.h:64:24: note: expected ‘const struct proc_ops *’ but argument is of type ‘struct file_operations *’
 struct proc_dir_entry *proc_create(const char *name, umode_t mode, struct proc_dir_entry *parent, const struct proc_ops *proc_ops);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-trunk-common/scripts/Makefile.build:273: /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build/acpi_call.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-trunk-common/Makefile:1696: /var/lib/dkms/acpi-call/1.1.0/build] Error 2
make: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-trunk-common/Makefile:180: sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.6.0-trunk-amd64'
```

I use Thinkpad X1 Extreme. I try to install this package/software to set battery thresolds with TLP. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel ≥ 5.6 needs at least package version 1.1.0-6 (Debian unstable or Ubuntu 20.10) which contains the necessary patch.

https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#installation-of-package-acpi-call-dkms-failed

Comment: thank you very much. It helped me fix the issue. But can you share with me how you found that?! I googled but didn't help..

Comment: I reported the bug in Debian https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=959729

Comment: The inspiration for the patch came from a fix for a similar compile error in ZFS (google result).

Comment: For my Linux (*Linux Mint 20*) the 1.1.0-6 was not yet available via the package repositories. But a manual installation of the *.deb package from http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/acpi-call/acpi-call-dkms_1.1.0-6_all.deb worked fine.